# Request method 'PUT' not supported spring mvc 4

Tags: spring-mvc

Following is my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/surveys")
public class SurveysController extends BaseController {

@PutMapping(value="/testPut")
@ResponseBody
public String testPut(){
    return "helloWorld";
}

}
```

Following is angular put method:

```
    var fd = new FormData();
    var that = this;
    fd.append($scope.csrfParamName, $scope.csrfToken);

    $http.put('/dmapp/surveys/testPut.html', fd, {
        transformRequest : angular.identity,
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
            '_csrf' : $scope.csrfToken
        }
    })
    .success(function(response) {
        callBack(response);
    })
    .error(function() {
    });
```

I am calling this function on load and getting Request Method PUT not supported. Why?

I am using spring mvc with spring data rest. same is happening with spring data rest. Morever delete verb is also acting in the same weird way. Only get and post are working

Comment: try removing the .html used in the JS or adding it to the mapping in spring.

Comment: still same error

Comment: try replace this ```@PutMapping(value="/testPut")``` with this ```@RequestMapping(value="/testPut", method= RequestMethod.PUT)```

Comment: still same. I am facing same problem with spring data rest. I am using both mvc and spring data rest. Do I have to configure somewhere to allow PUT, DELETE etc.?

Comment: Interestingly while starting the server I see this line "Mapped "{[/surveys/testPut],methods=[PUT]}" onto public...."

Comment: problem solved by adding csrf header name and csrf token in header